# Node.js 3D game?

Tags: node.js

Would it be suitable for making 3D games in an open world?

Of course provided that I :

- create a node add-on in order to bind opengl
- code a native layer for making threads and processes

I can almost hear you: why node? Because I love coffeescript and I am more experienced in that language (I can't get pointers in c++) and mostly because I want it to be cross platform and **hackable**.

But is node fast enough? Are programming patterns such as data locality working in node? What about CPU load?

Comment: "Fast enough" for what? Nobody else can test it on your game exactly.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at [Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and/or [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Comment: Are web workers threads? Anyway in node i should be using clusters shouldnt i ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using node for a game client is not the best option. Node.js is usually used for the server side of a game and not the client.

If you like CoffeScript why don't you create an HTML 5 game with one of the tons of free [JavaScript game engines out there](http://html5gameengine.com/)?

This would also spare you the hassle of creating OpenGL bindings (you'd have to use WebGL which is basically a subset of OpenGL).

Comment: This is a weak argument. "Usual" does not imply "best". OpenGL bindings for Node [exist already](https://github.com/hross/node-opengl). There may be other reasons not to use Node.js here, but these are not them.

Comment: @Anko what reasons?

Comment: @Vinz For example, lack of native threads. If you run a long compute-intensive task on the main thread, all else is pushed back, which could break a real-time application. There are [ways to cope](http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/), but these may or may not be feasible/necessary/desirable, depending on OP's exact use case.

Comment: @Anko thank you. My project is some kind of RPG in an open world